# How do I get the form generation wizard in Eclipse EE using JSF?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to get to the wizard that generates the form tag and content from data using the JSF HTML form available in eclipse's Palette window. However, upon dragging and dropping the form tag into the design view, no such dialog pops up. What am i doing wrong and how can I get to that wizard?

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to do that, if what you want is easy and fast I suggest the framework Primefaces or Bootstrap.

1- http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/

2- http://bootsnipp.com/forms

You only need to make some adjustments to the code generated with the second to use the JSF tags.

If you use the first one, the form will be ready to work and start programming the Backend.

** I suggest you to be documented at: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/